# StreamReader storing empty lines in list if string contains special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

The textfile contains hundreds of lines like this and almost all of them are stored in the list.
But the lines containing characters such as '-', '&' or dots ('.') are added to the list as empty lines.
Out of the lines below: the 1st, 2nd, 7th, 8th, 10th & 11th lines will be stored right, the others will be stored blank.
Afterwards, when i try to load the list into a dropdownlist, there's blank values inside the dropdownlist as well.

Code:

```
string singleLineSchedule;
List<string> courses = new List<string>();

public List<string> LoadStudentCourses()
{
try
{
    fileLoader = new StreamReader(@"C:\TestSchedule.txt", Encoding.Default, true);

    //Read one line at a time
    while ((singleLineSchedule = fileLoader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Will store any text from each line that is in between '> & </option>, for example: '>Course1</option>
        courses.Add(GetTextBetween(singleLineSchedule, "'>", "</option>"));
    }
}
catch
{
    courses.Add("Error loading schedule file");
}

fileLoader.Dispose();

return courses;
}

public static String GetTextBetween(String source, String leftWord, String rightWord)
{
return Regex.Match(source, String.Format(@"{0}(?<words>[\w\s]+){1}", leftWord, rightWord), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["words"].Value;
}
```

Part of the textfile where it gets the information(they're all option types):

```
 <option>year 1</option>
 <option>second year</option>
 <option>class 1 containing a special-character</option>
 <option>class 2 containing special-characters & such</option>
 <option>class 3 containing a special-character</option>
 <option>class 4 containing a special-character</option>
 <option>third year</option>
 <option>fourth year</option>
 <option>fifth year with a dot.</option>
 <option>value 4</option>
 Biology</option>
```

Comment: Just for test purpose try adding lines without Regex method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\w\s in regex doesn't allow other characters but a-z,A-Z,0-9, white-space, so the return value of GetTextBetween is empty if there's something else in the string.